# How to set variables with ./configure

Tags: php, c, compilation, configure

I am trying to compile and install a new PHP version next to my existing with pthreads.

Running `./configure`, the process is using my default system PHP variables,
not the ones I am in:

```
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php5/20100525
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php5
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
```

How can I change it to use `/usr/local/src/php-5.6.5/ext` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets the job done:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/src/php-5.6.5
```